# I have some error on symfony project in shared host

Tags: php, symfony

I'm a beginner in Symfony. I build a very simple project using Symfony that works correctly work in localhost. I upload all content of project folder expect 'web' in the root of my shared hosting and upload 'web' folder to 'public_html' folder. Import MySQL to my created database in host correctly and change 'parameters.yml' and change database connection details. Change chmod of '/var/logs/' and '/var/cache' to 777. But when going to website get an internal error.

Errors detail :

```
[24-Apr-2016 05:02:09 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Session Storage was not able to create directory "D:\eventcalendar\app/../var/sessions/prod"' in /home/emusummit/var/cache/prod/classes.php:292
Stack trace:

#0 /home/emusummit/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php(1898): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\NativeFileSessionHandler->__construct('D:\\eventcalenda...')

#1 /home/emusummit/var/bootstrap.php.cache(2107): appProdProjectContainer->getSession_HandlerService()

#2 /home/emusummit/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php(1937): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('session.handler')

#3 /home/emusummit/var/bootstrap.php.cache(2107): appProdProjectContainer->getSession_Storage_NativeService()

#4 /home/emusummit/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php(1885): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('session.storage...')

#5 /home/emusummit/var/bootstrap.php.cache(2107): appProdProjectContainer->getSessionService()

#6 /home/emusummit/var/cache/prod/c in /home/emusummit/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php on line 94
```

What is the problem? Please help me. Thanks

Comment: thoses dont look like paths a host would use.

Comment: @Dagon  //  i see that, but i dont know change 'D:\\eventcalendar' from where ?

Comment: has to be in your code somewhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably didn't clear the cache.

Try to clear the cache by running command:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Or if you use dev-environment (it is not right for production server) you shoud use:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

If you have no access to shell you can clear the cache manually by removing whole folder with the name of your environment from `var/cache`. For `prod` environment you should remove `var/cache/prod` folder.

Comment: i clear cache exactly with your help but get error again. i delete all content of '/var/cache' manually and solved problem and not get any error(s). thanks

Comment: In your error also seems that folder permission is causing error, so you should give it 777 permission to avoid this to the directories `/var/cache`, `/var/log` and `/var/session`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add **rwx** permission to the webserver user that is `www-data` on the session directory through act package if you don't have it install by

```
$ sudo apt-get install acl
```

if you do have it just type

```
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rX project-symfony/var/sessions
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rX project-symfony/var/sessions
```

the second line is to give permissions **rwx** to files under that dir
Best practices are to give **rx** permission to the project itself
**rwx** to `var/cache` `var/logs`  and  `var/sessions` ,**rwx** to its derivate (respectively as i did above ).

after that you need to clear cache [delete the `--env=prod` if you are in development mode] and you're good to go !

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```